# NoMachine NX 'p' key not working for Macbook Pro vs Fedora

Tags: macos, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, nomachine-nx

My 'p' key is dead within a NX session. I'm on a Macbook Pro with Snow Leopard (10.6.8) and I'm NX'ing into a Fedora instance. I NX into other machines and don't have the same problem.

I've read plenty on dead keys and odd mappings but nothing relating to the 'p' key. I've checked the modifiers via xmodmap -pm on both machines, there's no mention of the 'p' key.

I've run out of ideas.. Anyone else come across this?

Comment: Cool, it's not just me!..  What I do find interesting is that pressing the capslock and then doing shift-P will produce a lowercase P :-D..   so Shift-P works, just not p by itself.

Comment: Same here. 'p' and 'tab' is broken, it tried all workarounds but no luck. Btw. Shift-P creates an uppercase P on my system. It's Fedora 16/17 as server and Mac OS X 10.7 as client.

Answer (score 5):

This is caused by the two keyboard short-cuts using the "Windows" alias "Super" key
the 'p' and 'tab' keys works again if you remove those two short-cut in the (xfce) config.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not use signatures/taglines in your posts. Your user box counts as your signature, and you can use your profile to post any information about yourself you like. [FAQ on signatures/taglines](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures)

Comment: I don't think this related to nx or nomachine. It is just an xfce config indeed. To be more specific edit ~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts.xml and remove all entries containing 'super'. See http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1771058.html

Answer (score 0):

I find I lose the 'p' key when I shift focus from osx to the nx session. Tapping any modifier key (ctrl, option, command...) recovers it. Completely repeatable. I've tried various ways of logging the key presses, but it's as if the 'p' key is not being detected at all.

Mac Pro, 10.6.8 client, into Scientific Linux 6.2 (RHEL6.2 clone)